# Class \App\PasswordVerifier does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am using [OAuth laravel repo](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-with-the-Password-Grant), I set it up correctly but when trying to import a class for credentials, I run into 'class not found' error.

I have a function:

```
'grant_types' => [
      'password' => [
        'callback' => '\App\PasswordVerifier@verify',
                    ]
                 ]
```

My directory looks like this:

```
  app
    --PasswordVerifier.php
config
    --oauth.php (above chunk)
```

However, I am getting error:

> `ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
>   Class \App\PasswordVerifier does not exist`

PasswordVerifier.php looks like this:

```
  // namespace App\PasswordVerifier; - I tried with/without adding this line
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

  class PasswordVerifier
  {
      public function verify($username, $password)
    {
     ...
```

Note that changing `'callback' => '\App\PasswordVerifier@verify` is resulting in change in the name of class in the error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PasswordVerifier` class needs to be in the `App` namespace:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PasswordVerifier
{
   public function verify($username, $password)
   {
       ...
```

Think of the namespaces like folders (and actually, as far as the autoloader is concerned, they're the same).

The way the Autoloader works is that when you call a class, it will use the namespace as the folder tree, and the class name as the filename.

Everything should be case sensitive *except* for the base `app` folder, because the autoloader has been explicitly told to find anything in the `App` namespace in the `app` folder.